# Is it possible to use html tags in your database table, yet still use an external style sheet to style elements?

Tags: css, database, styling

I am using an AJAX call to pull data out from my database and push into certain `<div>`'s with an `id` using jQuery, however I'm struggling styling those elements which are being pulled out. Or would I have to do in-line styling inside of the db?

If I am popping in my html markup within the database, can I still use  an external style sheet to style them i.e: `<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` ? I have tried to do the below which does not work...

**Database snapshot:**
[image: Database]

**CSS:**

```
#testingDB{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to have anything to do with the phpMyAdmin application, which is a web-based interface for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB installation. I've edited your tags accordingly.

Comment: What you're proposing should be possible, but you need to show us more about how you're rendering the data (and perhaps how it's being retrieved) for anyone to know why it isn't working for you. You might not want to store the tags in the database, either; if it's possible to create them while rendering the page that's probably better than storing individual `<li>` tags in the database (that advice probably wouldn't apply if you're storing an entire article or page complete with all the associated markup, of course). Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. If it doesn't, do check the address bar URL, since it's possible that the relative link to the stylesheet resolves to elsewhere.

> `<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

Assuming `style.css` is at http://localhost/style.css and the page you load is at http://localhost/test/page.html, specifying `href="./style.css"` will instead try to load http://localhost/test/style.css which doesn't exist.

To validate this, press F12, click the network tab, filter by CSS and refresh the page. If it didn't load, the request will be in red.